# Change the value of a specific div's class

Tags: javascript

I have the code below and I need to change "bg-image-container" from `<div title="THISTEASER"` to "bg-image-container-big"

```
<div id="teaser_id" class="column class1 class2 class3 class4">
  <div class="teaser-class-xy">
    <a class="class6 class7 class8 class9" href="test" title="test">
      <div title="THISTEASER" class="bg-image-container is-displayed-mobile lazyload" data-bg="1400x1200.jpg"></div>
      <div title="THISTEASER" class="bg-image-container is-displayed-tablet lazyload" data-bg="1400x1200.jpg"></div>
      <div title="THISTEASER" class="bg-image-container is-displayed-desktop lazyload" data-bg="1400x1200.jpg"></div>
    </a>
```

With

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("teaser_id").classList.add('bg-image-container-big');
    }
```

I was able to change the ID but it didn't help me.

I cant use jquery nor I can't add an ID in HTML (otherwise i could change the class by myself). I don't need a button solution, the javascript has to be with window.onload automaticaly

The classes aren't unique also.

Hope you can help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way :

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('div[title="THISTEASER"]');
elems.forEach((e) => {
 e.classList.remove("bg-image-container")
  e.classList.add("bg-image-container-big")
});
```

Comment: [e..classList.replace('bg-image-container','bg-image-container-big')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/replace)

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can make this:

```
window.onload=function(){
  const divElements = document.querySelectorAll('div.bg-image-container');
  divElements.forEach((div) => {
    div.classList.remove("bg-image-container")
    div.classList.add("bg-image-container-big")
  });
}
```

Comment: Yeah but I don't want to add the bg-image-container-big to teaser_id, I need it for this: <div title="THISTEASER" class="bg-image-container is-displayed-mobile lazyload" data-bg="1400x1200.jpg"></div>

Comment: makes sense.
Edited the answer with another example.

I think you could make a reusable function so you can use it whenever you need it

Answer (score 0):

You can get all title and add a loop.

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('[title="THISTEASER"]');
elems.forEach((e) => {
 e.classList.remove("bg-image-container"));
 e.classList.add("bg-image-container-big"));
}
```

```html
<div id="teaser_id" class="column class1 class2 class3 class4">
  <div class="teaser-class-xy">
    <a class="class6 class7 class8 class9" href="test" title="test">
      <div title="THISTEASER" class="bg-image-container is-displayed-mobile lazyload" data-bg="1400x1200.jpg"></div>
      <div title="THISTEASER" class="bg-image-container is-displayed-tablet lazyload" data-bg="1400x1200.jpg"></div>
      <div title="THISTEASER" class="bg-image-container is-displayed-desktop lazyload" data-bg="1400x1200.jpg"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```